# How to improved performance of code when dealing with large input in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, optimization

How would it be possible to make this code run faster in C++. The code takes a lot of time to run. The purpose is to determine how many gates are required to handle a prescribed
arrivals-and-departures schedule.

```
#include <vector>

struct Airplane {
    int arrival_time_seconds;
    int departure_time_seconds;
};

class Schedule {
private:
    const std::vector<Airplane> airplanes_;

public:
    Schedule(const std::vector<Airplane>& airplanes) :
        airplanes_(airplanes) {}

    int MaximumNumberOfPlanes() const {
        int rv = 0;
        for (const Airplane& airplane : airplanes_) {
            int num_planes = NumberOfPlanes(airplane.arrival_time_seconds);
            if (num_planes > rv) {
                rv = num_planes;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }

private:
    int NumberOfPlanes(int time_seconds) const {
        int rv = 0;
        for (const Airplane& airplane : airplanes_) {
            if (airplane.arrival_time_seconds < time_seconds &&
                    time_seconds <= airplane.departure_time_seconds) {
                rv++;
            }
        }
        return rv;
    }
};
```

Comment: If there's nothing clearly wrong with your code then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for this kind of question.

Comment: Optimizing code should always be done based on measurements.
So have you actually run your code using a profiler to get those measurements?
I don't see anything very nasty in here, so maybe the slowness is somewhere else (like reading a text input file).

Comment: The quadratic algorithm is the issue, not the C++ code implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people stated that this can be made O(*N*), and it is possible to some extent. At least I was able to make it O(max(*N*,86400)) which is better than your version for *N*>294 and better than a O(*N*log*N*) for *N*>6788.

I assume that if a plane departs the next day it has a `departure_time_seconds = 86400` (the number of seconds in a day), while all `arrival_time_seconds` are lower than 86400.

You can compile a vector of the change in number of planes in O(*N*) and than use it to compute the current number of planes in the airport at every second in O(86400):

```
    int MaximumNumberOfPlanes2() const {
        int delta[24 * 60 * 60 + 1] = { 0 };
        for (const Airplane& x : airplanes_) {
            delta[x.arrival_time_seconds]++;
            delta[x.departure_time_seconds]--;
        }
        int rv = 0;
        int np = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24 * 60 * 60; ++i) {
            np += delta[i];
            rv = std::max(rv, np);
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

A test program with some timing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    default_random_engine eng;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> arr_dist(0, 24*60*60);
    gamma_distribution<double> dep_dist(5, 3);

    std::vector<Airplane> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        int arrival = arr_dist(eng);
        int departure = arrival + (20 + lround(dep_dist(eng))) * 60;
        departure = min(departure, 24*60*60);
        a.push_back({ arrival, departure });
    }

    Schedule s(a);
    {
        const auto& start = steady_clock::now();
        int mnp = s.MaximumNumberOfPlanes();
        const auto& stop = steady_clock::now();
        duration<double> elapsed = stop - start;
        std::cout << "MaximumNumberOfPlanes : " << mnp << " - Elapsed: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    }
    {
        const auto& start = steady_clock::now();
        int mnp = s.MaximumNumberOfPlanes2();
        const auto& stop = steady_clock::now();
        duration<double> elapsed = stop - start;
        std::cout << "MaximumNumberOfPlanes2: " << mnp << " - Elapsed: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives (on my laptop):

```
MaximumNumberOfPlanes : 2572 - Elapsed: 48.8979 s
MaximumNumberOfPlanes2: 2572 - Elapsed: 0.0010778 s
```

Comment: Why did you constrain to one day? An airplane might be parked for multiple days, which is actually the case.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher I guessed that storing the elapsed time in seconds, suggested a one day schedule. Let's see if the OP posts a clarification.

Comment: This is a fast solution for a *particular* case of the problem presented. It is not an answer for the problem posed.

Comment: @NoleKsum The problem as posed is missing context. Given that the arrival and departure time is in seconds and its a 32 bit value there is no way its "seconds since unix epoch". "seconds since midnight" seems like a perfectly reasonable and valid fallback assumption.

Comment: @Taekahn I believe you should review your math: 32-bits in seconds is about **136 years**.

Comment: @NoleKsum Perhaps i'm wrong, but it was my understanding that the time functions all return 64 bit numbers?

Comment: @Taekahn `time_t` can be 32 or 64 bits, depending on platform and flags how the application was compiled.Still, if you assign the resulting 64 bits to a 32 bits integer, you will have 136 years range. I fail to understand the point you are trying to carry around.